# Html Link Bounce only one Element with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Problem with my Jquery Code. When you hover the link in the list, bounce every menu_img class, but it should only bounce an element.

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <div class="bounce"></div> <a href="#">Test1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="bounce"></div> <a href="#">Test2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.menu li {
    list-style-type:none;
}
.bounce {
    position: absolut;
    height: 17px;
    width: 17px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    background-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Arrow_green2.png");
}
```

JS:

```
$("ul.menu > li a").hover(function () {
    doBounce(3, '2px', 200);
});


function doBounce(times, distance, speed) {
    for (i = 0; i <times; i++) {
        $(".bounce").animate({
            marginLeft: '-=' + distance
        }, speed)
            .animate({
            marginLeft: '+=' + distance
        }, speed);
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88LyP/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the hovered element to `doBounce()` like this

```
$("ul.menu > li a").hover(function () {
    doBounce($(this),3, '2px', 200); // Pass hovered element as $(this)
});


function doBounce(elementTobounce, times, distance, speed) {
    for (i = 0; i <times; i++) {
        $(elementTobounce).prev(".bounce").animate({
            marginLeft: '-=' + distance
        }, speed)
            .animate({
            marginLeft: '+=' + distance
        }, speed);
    }
}
```

`elementTobounce` is your hovered `a` element, then referring to your `.bounce` class with `.prev()` which is having an image `->` will get animated.

*Docs:*

[.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/88LyP/3/)

Comment: Thanks that is the solution for my problem =)

Comment: ..Welcome friend.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting your function to pass the referenced element - `$(this)` - to the `doBounce` function so that only the item that is currently being hovered is subjected.

```
$("ul.menu > li a").hover(function () {
    doBounce($(this), 3, '2px', 200);
});


function doBounce(el, times, distance, speed) {
    for (i = 0; i <times; i++) {
        el.prev('.bounce').animate({
            marginLeft: '-=' + distance
        }, speed)
            .animate({
            marginLeft: '+=' + distance
        }, speed);
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbeliv01/88LyP/2/)

Comment: Arrow should be bounce here not link text!

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you right.. you need to bounce arrow above your test text..

so you need to pass which element you want to bounce.

try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/88LyP/7/)

```
<div class="bounce" id="test1"></div> <a href="#">test1</a>
<div class="bounce" id="test2"></div> <a href="#">test2</a>

$("ul.menu > li a").hover(function () {
  var elementId = $(this)[0].text;
  doBounce(3, '2px', 200, elementId);
});


function doBounce(times, distance, speed, elementId) {
  for (i = 0; i <times; i++) {
    $("#"+elementId).animate({
        marginLeft: '-=' + distance
    }, speed)
        .animate({
        marginLeft: '+=' + distance
    }, speed);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why both elements are bouncing is that you are using $(.bounce) as the element being animated, which contains 2 li elements.

```
function doBounce(times, distance, speed, obj) {
for (i = 0; i <times; i++) {
    $(obj).animate({
        marginLeft: '-=' + distance
    }, speed)
        .animate({
        marginLeft: '+=' + distance
    }, speed);
  }
}


$("ul.menu > li").hover(function(){
    doBounce(3, "2px", 200, $(this));
})
```